# Pantheon files. Color of files and folders does not work (Juno)

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, color

Marking in color of files and folders works before updating (ctrl+R). After updating color of the file disappears.

pantheon-files_4.1.5+r3347+pkg78~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64

Comment: yesterday files were updated. the problem remained

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of this issue: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/892

This was fixed in the master branch a couple of weeks ago so it should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: yesterday files were updated. the problem remained

Comment: Please reboot or other make sure that the pantheon-files daemon restarts. Hopefully that will fix it.  If not, check there are no old ctag plugin files in or below `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.files/plugins/`.   If the problem persists please raise a new issue on github.

Comment: Today files were updated. Now everything works. Thank you very much!!